# console.log is not printed inside of casper.evaluate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to write a small scraper with casper, but I'm not able to get the evaluate function work. This is my code,

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["bower_components/jquery/src/jquery.js"],
     verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'info'
});

casper.start('http://stackoverflow.com', function afterStart() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    if (this.exists(".js-headword")) {
        //This gets executed
        this.echo("Meh!")
    }
    //If this is enabled the above code doesn't work. 

    // this.echo(this.fetchText(".js-headword"))
});
casper.then(function evalPage(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        //This does not. 
        console.log("Evaluating title");
    })
})

casper.run();
```

and this is my casper log

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[info] [phantom] Step afterStart 2/3 http://stackoverflow.com/ (HTTP 200)
Stack Overflow
Meh!
[info] [phantom] Step afterStart 2/3: done in 5960ms.
[info] [phantom] Step evalPage 3/3 http://stackoverflow.com/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step evalPage 3/3: done in 5982ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 6002ms
```

The code hits the evalPage function, but it does not run the evaluate method. The console.log is never reached. I'm following the documentation and completely clueless why this is not working.

I'm running casper 1.1 beta 3 on OSX10.10.

EDIT 1 :

I'm trying to perform some DOM manipulation inside evaluate(). For instance, if the page has an h1 tag, I need to get the text inside the h1 tag.

```
this.evaluate(function(){
    //This does NOT work

    console.log(document.querySelector("h1").textContent)

})
```

The console.log is an oversimplified version of what I'm trying to do. My understanding about the evaluate method is it's in the current page context and I can perform and DOM manipulation in that. But I've not been able to achieve this.

reference : http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. Edited the question again.

Comment: What I've given here is an oversimplification. The point I'm trying to make here is that whatever code I'm writing inside the evaluate doesn't seem to work. Even I've tried returning a string and capturing it outside, but that didn't work. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here and would love to understand how to get this working.

Comment: You mean `this.echo(this.evaluate(function(){return "string";}));` doesn't print "string"? What CasperJS and PhantomJS version do you have?

Comment: When I execute your script with CasperJS 1.1-beta3 and PhantomJS 1.9.8 on Win7, it doesn't print "Meh", but does print "Evaluating title"

Comment: Can you try changing the selector ".js-headword" to "#header". I made a mistake while copying the code.

Comment: I'm running  casper1.1-beta3 and phantom 1.9.7 on Mac OSX 10.10

Comment: Yes, [it works](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/e0c0c0e9b33307e14416)

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me. I'll try reinstalling casper and phantom to their latest version.